# Can I clone sprite in WYSIWYG but not in code?

Tags: mit-scratch

I have a sprite and need place several clones of it in the scene. I know how do it in code but the sprites have to be static all the time. I want to place and arrange them manually in editor before running the program.

Note: I need the cloned sprite as an entity of the same "class" in the scene but not copy it as one more "class" in spite palette.

I can't find such an option. Is it possible? How to do it?

Answer (score 1):

That block is in the Pen Extension of Scratch 3.0 as the Stamp block

Comment: [Stamp](https://en.scratch-wiki.info/wiki/Stamp_(block)) still exists in Scratch 3.0, as part of the [pen extension](https://en.scratch-wiki.info/wiki/Pen_Extension).

Comment: @RuudHelderman Oh.. Yeah! I just forgot but anyways!